# sfinae ambiguous call when passing 0 instead of 1

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

Relevant code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<template<typename...> class C, typename... T>
struct is_valid_instantiation_impl
{
  // Default constructor
  template<template<typename...> class D>
  static std::true_type test(decltype(D<T...>{ })*, int);
  // Copy constructor
  template<template<typename...> class D>
  static std::true_type test(decltype(D<T...>{ std::declval<const D<T...>&>() })*, long);
  // Move constructor
  template<template<typename...> class D>
  static std::true_type test(decltype(D<T...>{ std::declval<D<T...>&&>() })*, int*);

  template<template<typename...> class D>
  static std::false_type test(...);

  using type =  decltype(test<C>(nullptr, 1));
  //                                      ^ this one
};

template<template<typename...> class C, typename... T>
struct is_valid_instantiation : is_valid_instantiation_impl<C, T...>::type { };

template<typename>
struct tester;

template<>
struct tester<int>
{
  tester(int);
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  std::cout << "instantiable<int>: " << is_valid_instantiation<tester, int>::value << std::endl;
}
```

This code compiles fine, but when I replace that `1` by a `0` I get (Clang 3.4)

```
xxx: error: call to 'test' is ambiguous
  using type =  decltype(test<C>(nullptr, 0));
                         ^~~~~~~
xxx: note: in instantiation of template class 'is_valid_instantiation_impl<tester, int>' requested here
...

xxx: note: candidate function [with D = tester]
  static std::true_type test(decltype(D<T...>{ std::declval<const D<T...>&>() })*, long);
                        ^
xxx: note: candidate function [with D = tester]
  static std::true_type test(decltype(D<T...>{ std::declval<D<T...>&&>() })*, int*);
                        ^
xxx: note: candidate function [with D = tester]
  static std::false_type test(...);
                         ^
```

Why is it that suddenly this call is ambiguous? As far as I know `0` is still an int (*and GCC 4.8.2 seems to agree with me, but won't compile it either*):

```
xxx: error: call of overloaded ‘test(std::nullptr_t, int)’ is ambiguous
```

**EDIT:**

Please note I'm not asking how to resolve this ambiguity, but why there is an ambiguity when I use `0` instead of `1`.
See [this live example](http://ideone.com/K9uwrk) for the full code showing the error.

Comment: What you put in the question compiles, with either `1` or `0`, even after instantiating it with a dummy `tester` template class. Please post something that actually demonstrates the problem you're asking about.

Comment: What happens if you replace with `using type = decltype(test<C>(nullptr, static_cast<int>(0)));`?

Comment: @hvd Since I think it's a little too much code for my question, see [this live example](http://ideone.com/K9uwrk)

Comment: `0` is a null pointer constant, so you're facing a problem where it can either be converted to a pointer or another integral type. You obviously don't face that problem with `1` because it is not.

Comment: @0x499602D2 This is the answer I'm after.

Comment: @TomKnapen Thanks. I've reduced it a bit, left out the bits that aren't necessary for demonstrating the problem, and what's left is a little bit on the large side, but not too big for a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what your `C` and `D` are, but basically you have these two overloads:

```
static std::true_type test(X*, long);
static std::true_type test(Y*, int*);

test(nullptr, 0);
```

`nullptr` matches both of the first arguments, and `0` matches both of the second. Both overloads are viable, and neither is a better candidate than the other. Hence:

> error: call of overloaded `‘test(std::nullptr_t, int)’` is ambiguous

The reason that `0` can pass for `int*` is because, from [conv.ptr]:

> A *null pointer constant* is an **integer literal with value zero** or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the *null pointer value* of that type
>   and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function pointer type.

Comment: Still compiles on latest versions of [clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/cldasz7cZeVG3Y6Z) and [gcc](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/uprT3n3JkD3vfvch).

Comment: @0x499602D2 Not if you add `C() = delete;` It works because the `(X*, int)` overload is better than the other two.

Answer (score 0):

In some C++ compilers (most? I'm not sure), nullptr is defined as 0.  If you're using managed pointers, then nullptr and 0 are defined differently.  But for native pointers, they're the same thing.

So your code is hitting this literal 0, and the compiler suddenly doesn't know whether that's supposed to be a pointer or an integer, because technically it could be either.  Whereas "1" is defined in C++ to be a literal int, so there's no confusion.

Unfortunately, I don't see any way around it other than a cast to explicitly tell the compiler what 0 is supposed to mean.

Comment: *"In some C++ compilers (most? I'm not sure), nullptr is defined as 0"*, `nullptr` is a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. a null pointer constant of integral type (like `0`) can be converted to `std::nullptr_t`, but the opposite way won't work. `nullptr` is not `0`.

Comment: To add to @PiotrS.'s comment, you're probably thinking of `NULL` rather than `nullptr`. `NULL` is a macro that does almost always expand to `0` or `0L`, but that isn't what the OP is using.